# inverse function of series

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, functions, radicals, inverse-function

Consider

$$f(x)=e^{0A}+e^{1A}+e^{2A}+…$$

Where $A=1/\log x.$

I’m interested in the inverse of $f.$ I think $f^{-1}(x)=e^{A(g(x))}$ for some radical expression $g$.

For a truncated sum Wolfram alpha gives closed forms for $g$ but they get very complex.

What is the rule to obtain $g$? I presume it involves finding roots of polynomials in which the degree tends to infinity. At least wolfram alpha seems to be doing that.

Comment: Are you looking for the inverse of the infinite sum or truncated sum?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The series for $f$ is geometric. It converges if $e^A<1$, i.e. $A<0$ which occurs if $0<x<1$. Therefore,

$$0<x<1\implies f(x)=\frac{1}{1-e^{\frac{1}{\log x}}}$$

This function is continuous in this range, and monotone (decreasing) so that it is invertible.

The inverse is

$$f^{-1}(x)=\exp\left(\frac{1}{\log \left(1-\frac{1}{x}\right)}\right)$$

for $x>1$.

Comment: +1 but continuity and monotonicity are useless: to determine the range and prove the invertibility, it suffices to solve for $x\in(0,1)$, as you did, the equation $y=\frac{1}{1-e^{\frac{1}{\log x}}}$ (the solution $x$ exists iff $y>1$ and is then unique,  $x=\exp\left(\frac{1}{\log \left(1-\frac1y\right)}\right)$).

Comment: Well monotonicity implies injectivity, which implies bijective onto its image, so invertible with the right codomain...

Comment: Indeed, but what I mean is that all this reasoning was useless once you solved the equation, which you anyway had to do.